# How to add lowercase normalizer to Elasticsearch mapping object in a particular field?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a schema published into an elastic, and I want to know if is possible add a lowercase normalizer when the index is published in order to update that field and avoid define a new schema object with all old fields and the new one.

Currently I am triying to update that field with this command:

```
await this.getClient().indices.putSettings({index: indexName, body:{ 
  softwarePublisher: {
    type: "text",
    fields: {
      ngram: {
        type: "text",
        analyzer: "software_analyzer",
        search_analyzer: "software_search_analyzer",
      },
      raw: {
        type: "keyword",
      },
      rawl: {
        type: "keyword",
        normalizer: "lowercase_normalizer",
      },
    },
  },
}});
```

But I got the following error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.ngram.analyzer] please check
> that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.ngram.analyzer] please check
> that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.ngram.search_analyzer] please
> check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking
> changes documentation for removed
> settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.ngram.type] please check that
> any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.raw.type] please check that
> any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.rawl.normalizer] please check
> that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.fields.rawl.type] please check that
> any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes
> documentation for removed
> settings"},{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown
> setting [index.softwarePublisher.type] please check that any required
> plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for
> removed settings"}]},"status":400}

I tried to with putMappings but anyway I got an error.

**EDIT**

Elastic version

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "bf9cd8c528fc",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "MzMfZzJaQwia1A5U5SFzNg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.1.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "7a013de",
    "build_date" : "2019-05-23T14:04:00.380842Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Error using putMapping

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
> mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [publisher :
> {type=text, fields={rawl={normalizer=lowercase_normalizer,
> type=keyword}, raw={type=keyword},
> ngram={search_analyzer=software_search_analyzer,
> analyzer=software_analyzer,
> type=text}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
> mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [publisher :
> {type=text, fields={rawl={normalizer=lowercase_normalizer,
> type=keyword}, raw={type=keyword},
> ngram={search_analyzer=software_search_analyzer,
> analyzer=software_analyzer, type=text}}}]"},"status":400}

Analyzer

```
export const softwareNameAnalyzer = {
  filter: {
    ngram_custom: {
      type: "edge_ngram",
      min_gram: "1",
      max_gram: "15",
    },
  },
  tokenizer: {
    software_tokenizer,
  },
  normalizer: {
    lowercase_normalizer: {
      filter: ["lowercase"],
    },
  },
  analyzer: {
    software_search_analyzer: defaultAnalyzer,
    software_analyzer: softwareAnalyzer,
    default: defaultAnalyzer,
    default_search: defaultAnalyzer,
  },
};

export const softwareAnalyzer = {
  type: "custom",
  tokenizer: "software_tokenizer",
  char_filter: ["html_strip"],
  filter: ["lowercase", "ngram_custom"],
};
```

Any idea?

Thanks?

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: just updated with the version info

Comment: You should use `putMappings()` not `putSettings()` since you're defining fields. What error do you get with `putMappings()`?

Comment: Also how do you define your custom analyzers?

Comment: Just update with the info thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should use `putMappings()` not `putSettings()` since you're defining fields.

Then you must invoke `putMappings()` as follows (you're missing the `properties` section):

```
await this.getClient().indices.putMappings({index: indexName, body:{ 
  properties: {                            <<----- add this
      softwarePublisher: {
         ...
      }
  }
}});
```

Note: You need to make sure to invoke `putSettings()` before `putMappings` so that your custom analyzers are installed first, otherwise the `putMappings()` call will complain that your custom analyzers don't exist.

Comment: How I call putSettings before? with empty value like putSettings(); putMappings({index: indexName, body:{...?

Comment: No, you need to provide your [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_indices_putsettings)

Comment: ok thx, for the answer.